# How to run pl on windows

Tags: perl

I installed Perl (Strawberry) on Windows 10. I am trying to run `itunes_backup2hashcat.pl` to get the hashes needed for hashcat.

How to run my `manifest.plist` file to get:

```
$itunes_backup$*<ver>*<WPKY>*<ITER>*<SALT>*<DPIC>*<DPSL>`
```

I open the program and open command line (`C:\Users\Gaming\Documents>`). I am stuck here.

Comment: With a file association (which I believe the SP installer creates for you), all you need to do `itunes_backup2hashcat.pl` or `c:\path\to\itunes_backup2hashcat.pl` if it's not in the current dir.

Comment: Without a file association, you can use `perl itunes_backup2hashcat.pl` or `perl c:\path\to\itunes_backup2hashcat.pl`.

Comment: Of course, the script probably needs arguments. You'll need to provide them, whatever they are.

Answer (score 0):

get it by installing msys2; https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/latest/download

about ~ 191 Mb then

```
pacman -S perl
```

~51 Mb and get CPAN from there ~ 273 Mb